# How to store a UTF-16 character as a string in c#?

Tags: c#, utf

How can I print a character whose UTF-16 representation is feff2031?

When I try the following I get "?" as the result:

```
String million = "\u2030";
```

The character I want is "per million".  See [PER MILLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm) for more information.

```
UTF-8 (hex)     0xE2 0x80 0xB0 (e280b0)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000000:10110000
UTF-16 (hex)    0x2030 (2030)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8240
UTF-32 (hex)    0x00002030 (2030)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8240
C/C++/Java source code  "\u2030"
Python source code  u"\u2030"
```

Comment: Where are you trying to print i? Winform? Webform? Other?

Comment: Where are you trying to print it to? Odds are the character you're trying to print just isn't in the character set of your output device.

Comment: Isn't "\u2030" working? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: "\u2030" is not working cause i tryed that.. System.Console.write(million) - given million as above.. I am trying to print that in WINFORM..

Comment: Console.Writeline won't display it, because the font being used by the console doesn't support it. It should show up fine in a windows form.

Answer (score 3):

```
        label1.Text = "\u2030";
```

That shows up in a windows form I just tried;[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);`